# How do I put the tkinter entry boxes to be on the same line?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, raspbian, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry

I have been having trouble figuring out how to put my entry boxes on the same line (entry,entry2,entry3), I’ve tried checking around the internet but none of them had the solution to my problem.
Here is the basic code(I’m using my raspbian atm):

```
import curses, time
import Tkinter as Alarm
class test(Alarm.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Alarm.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.prompt = Alarm.Label(self, text="Enter hours (Max: 24 hours) , minutes, seconds:", anchor="w")
        self.entry = Alarm.Entry(self, width=1)
        self.entry2 = Alarm.Entry(self, width=1)
        self.entry3 = Alarm.Entry(self, width=1)
        self.prompt2 = Alarm.Label(self, text="Alarm Message:", anchor="w")
        self.entry4 = Alarm.Entry(self)
        self.output = Alarm.Label(self, text="00:00:00",font=(24))
        self.submit = Alarm.Button(self, text="Start", command = self.startTimer)
        self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=10)
        self.entry2.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=10)
        self.entry3.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=10)
        self.prompt2.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry4.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
        self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="bottom")
```

I copied and pasted a majority of the code from my actual file so there may be some irrelevant code here and there.

Comment: Did you try to search for the `grid` method?

Comment: I thought about that but I don’t know where to put it

Comment: [Here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) is a good place to start.

Comment: I tried but then I found out that I would have to adjust my coding a decent amount to use grid because I’m already using pack().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really insist on using pack, i would suggest you to add a frame in the middle just for the entries.

```
class test(Alarm.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Alarm.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.prompt = Alarm.Label(self, text="Enter hours (Max: 24 hours) , minutes, seconds:", anchor="w")
        self.prompt2 = Alarm.Label(self, text="Alarm Message:", anchor="w")
        self.entry4 = Alarm.Entry(self)
        self.output = Alarm.Label(self, text="00:00:00",font=(24))
        self.submit = Alarm.Button(self, text="Start", command = self.startTimer)
        self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        mid_frame = Alarm.Frame(self)
        mid_frame.pack()
        self.entry = Alarm.Entry(mid_frame, width=1)
        self.entry2 = Alarm.Entry(mid_frame, width=1)
        self.entry3 = Alarm.Entry(mid_frame, width=1)
        self.entry.pack(side="left", fill="x",padx=10)
        self.entry2.pack(side="left",fill="x", padx=10)
        self.entry3.pack(side="left",fill="x", padx=10)
        self.prompt2.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry4.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
        self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="bottom")
        self.pack()
```